# How to distinguish iPod/iPhone/iPad device information in Compile time?

Tags: iphone

My apps are a lot of cpu and memory are affected by.
So a different unit divided by the variable must be initialized. But this I would like to know at compile time rather than at runtime.
Runtime hours can know how to distinguish.
How do I distinguish at compile time?

Know how to distinguish between OS versions, which I do not know the law to distinguish between devices.

The following code is only os divide. but, i would like to detailed device information.
(iPod Touch 3/iPod Touch4/ iPhone3GS/ iPhone4/ iPhone4S/ iPad/ iPad2)

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED <= __IPHONE_4_0
    const static NSTimeInterval TIME_INTERVAL = 0.3;
#elif __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED > __IPHONE_4_0
    const static NSTimeInterval TIME_INTERVAL = 0.1;
#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be pretty obvious that there is no way to decide at compile time which device your code runs on. All devices run the same executable. The only possible distinction that could be made at compile time would be the one between armv6 (everything older than the iPhone 3Gs) and armv7.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot know at compile time what device the application is being run on - you compile a single application that should run on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
BOOL iPad = NO;
#if (__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 30200 )
if( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ) {
    iPad = YES;
}
#else
isPad = NO;
#endif
```

But it will only work on OS 3.2 or greater. It is still not resolved at compile time, but it should get you the correct device.

Comment: Also check: https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension for libs to help determine device info.